# Synchronize threads without modifying the parent class

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I`m working with the following design in Python 2.7:

- a master class
- a child class which extends Thread
- the master class starts a number of children

In each child, I need to call a method from the master class, but that method works correctly only if all the children are started. I tried to sync the children with a `Barrier`, like this:

```
  if self.barrier is None:
        self.barrier = Barrier(len(child_list));
        for d in child_list:
            d.barrier= self.barrier;
```

This does not work, as many of the barriers are None in the end.

How can I synchronize the children to wait for each other, and wait to call the method until all of them are up? **I can`t modify the master class.**

Comment: Is that code you added in the master that you can't change, or is each child mutating all of its siblings without any synchronization in an attempt to add a synchronization mechanism?

Comment: the added code is from child for sync, I can change it.

Comment: So each child is creating a new barrier and trying to add it (overwriting any existing attribute of the same name from earlier-started children) to each already-started child? Yeah, that's not going to work.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] so we can see the exact sequencing instead of just your description of the design?

Comment: yes abarnet, that was what I tried to do.  I will post the example in a few minutes.

Comment: Can you create the `Barrier` (in a global, unfortunately) before starting the threads?